# wsdl2java using Axis 1.4 in Gradle

Tags: gradle, ant, axis

I searched for plugins and tutorials but neither of them worked in the given context:
I'd like to generate server-side Java classes from a list of given WSDL files. They have to be generated with Axis 1.4 and Java 1.7.

My half-working code is the following:

```
configurations {
    axisGenAntTask
}

task genWsdlClasses() {
    doLast {
        def wsdlDir = file(axisInputDir)
        def wsdlFiles = new FileNameByRegexFinder().getFileNames("${wsdlDir}", /.*\.wsdl/)
        wsdlFiles.each { String wsdlFile ->
            ant.echo(message: "Generating Classes for use with WSDL")
            ant.taskdef(
                    name: "genClassesFromWSDL",
                    classname: "org.apache.axis.tools.ant.wsdl.Wsdl2javaAntTask",
                    classpath: configurations.axisGenAntTask.asPath
            )

            ant.genClassesFromWSDL(
                    url: wsdlFile,
                    output: file(cxfOutputDir)
            )
        }
    }
}

tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    dependsOn genWsdlClasses
}

dependencies {
    axisGenAntTask "org.apache.axis:axis-ant:1.4",
            "org.apache.axis:axis:1.4",
            "org.apache.axis:axis-jaxrpc:1.4",
            "axis:axis-wsdl4j:1.5.1",
            "commons-codec:commons-codec:1.3",
            "commons-logging:commons-logging:1.1.1",
            "commons-discovery:commons-discovery:0.2"
}
```

However, a generated CustomException class doesn't extend `Exception`, thus it is not throwable and Java code compilation isn't working (see similar question here: [Exception classes generated using Axis2 wsdl2java don't extend Exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9828442/exception-classes-generated-using-axis2-wsdl2java-dont-extend-exception)).

Somehow I would just have to tell `ant.taskdef` not to "unpack" the classes, as I read in the referenced SO-question, but the mentioned arguments are from Axis 2, not from the needed Axis 1.4 though.